# Ng-repeat doesn't show data

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS and currently on learning PHP RESTful service with angularjs.I had a problem that why was my response data doesn't show in ng-repeat ?

this is code structure:

```
<html ng-app="ngTest">
    <head>

    <title>Angular Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="GetCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.email }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ngTest = angular.module('ngTest',[]);

        ngTest.factory('GetFactory',function($http){
                var users = [];
                var factory = {};

                factory.getUsers = function(){
                    $http.get('api/get.php');
                    return users;
                };
                return factory;
            });



        ngTest.controller('GetCtrl',function($scope,GetFactory){
                    $scope.users = GetFactory.getUsers();

        });


        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP code contain dummy basic json response data :

```
<?php 
$dummyData = array(
    'email'=>'malikperang@gmail.com',
    'password'=>'admin321',
    );
$jsonen = json_encode($dummyData);
print_r($jsonen);

?>
```

What is wrong here?

**Update**:
Please scroll to @Koddi answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `$data` variable defined.

It should be

`$jsonen = json_encode($dummyData);`

instead of

`$jsonen = json_encode($data);`

Comment: Oh sorry!! It's my eye fault. urgh. thanks bro but fixing it still doesn't make the ng-repeat show the response data. :(

Comment: @MalikPerang, I never worked with _angular.js_ . I think the problem is in there , not with PHP. Which tutorial are you following ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my edited answer. Please check inline comments for explanations.

```
<title>Angular Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-resource.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="GetCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.email }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ngTest = angular.module('ngTest',[]);

        ngTest.factory('GetFactory',function($http)
        {
                var users = [];
                var factory = {};

                factory.getUsers = function(){
                    // the problem was here.
                    // as @Michael Butler pointed out.    
                    // Next, Best practices is to return the $http.get
                    // so you can play with promises callbacks 
                    // in the caller controller (as GetCtrl).
                    // promise callbacks : success() & .error
                    var userGetRequest = $http.get('api/get.php');
                    return userGetRequest;
                };
                return factory;
        });

        ngTest.controller('GetCtrl',function($scope,GetFactory)
        {
                    $scope.users = [];

                    GetFactory.getUsers()
                    .success(function(response)
                    {
                        // the api request was OK.
                        // we push because get by default return an object
                        // and here users is an array.
                        $scope.users.push(response);
                        console.log(response); // check navigator console for the server response
                    })
                    .error(function(response)
                    {
                        // something went wrong with the api request
                        console.log(response); // check navigator console for the server response
                    });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You may note that var users inside the factory is useless for now 'cause we're returning directly the promise as result of the call. But if you want to feed it with the get result, create a getSuccess function inside the factory like following:

```
var getSuccess = function(response) 
{
  // we push because get by default return an object
  // and here users is an array.
  users.push(response);    
}
```

And inside the factory.getUsers:

```
var userGetRequest = $http.get('api/get.php');
userGetRequest.success(getSuccess);
return userGetRequest;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi @koddi ,your given solution still doesn't solved my problem. :(

Comment: Thanks @koddi! it's worked. finally I'm clear know when how to use factory and controller with callback.

Comment: Glad to help you. Please don't forget to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `print_r`, use `print` instead to print out the data. `print_r` adds additional formatting that won't be valid JSON.

**Update:**

This part doesn't look right:

```
$http.get('api/get.php');
return users;
```

I'm not too familiar with AngularJS yet, but don't you need to assign something to the users variable? It looks like you are just calling the `get.php` AJAX request without storing the result anywhere.

Comment: Hi @michael changin print_r() to print() still not solve my problem